# Jsp can't get session attribute value

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I wrote a servlet.

```
request.setAttribute("itemCount", 1000);
request.getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

And in test.jsp I wrote:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<% 
String name=(String)session.getAttribute("itemCount"); 
out.print("Total items are: "+name); 
%>
<p>Number of items: ${itemCount} </p>
</body>
</html>
```

But the second row is

> Number of items: 1000

while the first row is

> Total items are null

So what's the issue?Any help? Thx.

Comment: You're setting the attribute on the request and reading it from the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your servlet, you can try using:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("itemCount", 1000);
```

& then in your jsp, you can access `itemCount` the way you are accessing.

Or alternatively,

use

```
<% 
String name=(String)request.getAttribute("itemCount");
```

in your jsp if you don't want to change any code in servlet (also mentioned by tgdavies in comment)